# Firebird Trigger: Modify Value & Insert Record

Tags: triggers, firebird

I am currently new in Firebird, especially in triggers. Usually, I do this in script manually, but I am really fascinated to create it with trigger.

Please let me explain my tables first.

```
***STOCK***
CODE
NAME
TOTAL
GOOD
BROKEN
SERVICE
***DETAIL***
ID
STOCK_CODE
SERIAL
***BROKEN***
DETAIL_ID
MARK
***SERVICE***
DETAIL_ID
START_DATE
END_DATE
COST
***LOGS***
DETAIL_ID
MARK
START_DATE
END_DATE
COST
```

And now my problems:

1. How to modify STOCK.GOOD and STOCK.BROKEN value after insert a new record into BROKEN? That will be: STOCK.GOOD-1, STOCK.BROKEN+1.
2. How to insert all record from BROKEN and SERVICE into LOGS before current record in SERVICE is deleted?

I hope my questions could be accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I mean AFTER INSERT, not BEFORE INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_broken FOR broken
  BEFORE INSERT
  POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE stock SET good = good - 1, broken = broken + 1
    WHERE code = (SELECT d.stock_code 
      FROM detail d WHERE d.id = NEW.detail_id);
END


CREATE TRIGGER bd_service FOR service
  BEFORE DELETE
  POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO logs (detail_id, mark, start_date, end_date, cost)
  SELECT detail_id, (SELECT b.mark FROM broken b WHERE b.detail_id = OLD.detail_id),
    start_date, end_date, cost
  FROM service 
  WHERE detail_id = OLD.detail_id;
END
```

By the way, what is a reason to put mark into a separate table? It belongs to STOCK, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should belongs to STOCK. :) But, there's a problem. DETAIL_ID on BROKEN is equivalent with ID on DETAIL. It should be WHERE code = NEW.code_id. But how?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am really new in trigger. What does 'd' and 'b' mean? d.id, b.detail_id, etc. Should it be the table name? e.g, STOCK.code, DETAIL.id? Thanks.

Comment: Oh I see. Is it okay if I use table name directly?

Comment: What for? Aliases are for distinguishing tables in queries where the same table involved several times.

Comment: Thank you for your helps, Mr. Andrei. I really appreciate it. :)